# how do you make a 3d cube visual with 8 different colored octants using plotly in python?

Tags: 3d, plotly

how do you make a 3d cube visual with 8 different colored octants using plotly in python?

So far I have been able to make the cube I wanted using matplotlib however I'd like to be able to recreate the cube using plotly so that I have an interactive visual.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your result with matplotlib, so that we understand what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To get a cube consisting in 8 sub-cubes, placed in each octant, one defines a `template_cube` in the first octant (i.e. the octant corresponding to x, y, z ≥ 0), and one translates this one in the directions defined by the rows in the array T, defined below. Then each of the eight sub-cubes are triangulated and represented as an instance of go.Mesh3d:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

template_cube = np.array([[0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 0],
                          [1, 1, 0],
                          [0, 1, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1],
                          [1, 0, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 1, 1]], dtype=float)
triangles=np.array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [6, 7, 4],
       [5, 1, 2],
       [2, 6, 5],
       [4, 0, 3],
       [3, 7, 4],
       [6, 2, 3],
       [3, 7, 6],
       [4, 5, 1],
       [1, 0, 4]], dtype=int)
I, J, K= triangles.T

colors=['#ce84e1',
 '#87479d',
 '#f4709a',
 '#f0a5c1',
 '#f7e3fd',
 '#b14359',
 '#5e0943',
 '#e7d5f9'       
 ]

T= [[0,0,0], [0, 0, -1], [0,-1, 0], [0, -1, -1], 
    [-1, 0, 0 ], [-1, 0, -1], [-1, -1, 0], [-1, -1, -1]]
mdata=[]
for n, tr in enumerate(T):
    vertices= template_cube+tr
    x, y, z = vertices.T
    mdata.append(go.Mesh3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, i=I, j=J, k=K, 
                           vertexcolor = [colors[n]]*8))
fig=go.Figure(mdata)    
fig.update_layout(width=400, height=400,  font_size=11,
                 scene_camera_eye=dict(x=1.7, y=1.7, z=0.9))
```